# How can I make twitter bootstrap 3 carousel centre the active image and show part of the next and previous images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So that the active image is animated to the centre and you get a hint of the previous and next images.

This seems like it should be fairly straight forward to do but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The images that aren't in view are hidden. And if you unhide them they are actually above one another.

It looks like your best option is to find a different library or roll your own. Trying to rewrite the CSS would be more work than its worth. There are plenty of carousel libraries out there.

- [this one has fancy effects](http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html)
- [this looks close to what you are talking about](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/)